# Error al correr proyecto react native

Tags: react-native

Hola acabo de instalar `react native` y no tuve ningún problema hasta el paso de poner el siguiente `comando`:

```
npx react-native run android
```

Al poner el comando me sale el siguiente error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguna solución? Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo uso [expo.io](http://expo.io) para ejecutar las app. Se abre el navegador con un código de barras que luego con la app Expo en Android puedes leer y se ejecuta la app en tu movil Android. Porque si no, tienes que tener instalado Android Studio y ocupa un montón y es tedioso de configurar. Expo.io es facil y sobre todo, a la hora de generar el fichero para subir a Google Play console. Lo mismo te pasaría con iOS, deberías tener un Mac para ejecutar la app y con Expo.io no es necesario.

Los pasos:

#### Instalación

```
npm install --global expo-cli
```

#### Crear aplicación

```
expo init calculator42
```

#### Arrancar el emulador

```
cd calculator42
expo start
```

#### Construir la app para descargar el fichero .aab

```
expo build:android -t app-bundle
```

Luego vas a la web, te descargas el fichero .AAB y ya lo puedes subir a Google Play Console.

Comment: doy fe, expo es utilísimo

Comment: Al crear un proyecto me pide seleccionar una de 5 opciones, cual me recomiendan para empezar a aprender sobre esto?

Comment: Yo siempre uso la más sencilla, creo que es la primera.

Answer (score 1):

El error es que no has configurado bien el entorno de desarrollo, es verdad que con **Expo** es mucho más sencillo de empezar, sin embargo si vas a desarrollar una app de manera más profesional es recomendado hacerlo a través del CLI de react-native.

Tenes que seguir la documentación al pie de la letra.
Básicamente lo más importante de la [documentación](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup) son las siguientes cosas a tener en cuenta:

1. Node JS
2. Open JDK (Java Development Kit)
3. Android Studio
4. Variables de entorno **ANDROID_HOME** y **JAVA_HOME**
5. Agregar platform-tools al PATH

Después de asegurarte de tener esto bien instalado y un ADV (Android Virtual Device) no deberías tener ningún problema. Son muchos ítems que pide tener instalado React Native pero créeme que una vez que tienes el entorno montado es muy sencillo.

Repito, si es para empezar y ver si te gusta el lenguaje, te recomiendo que empieces por Expo, en cambio si quieres desarrollar algo no tan simple te recomiendo el CLI de RN.

Comment: Hola tengo el mismo error, y una pregunta, a que te refieres con las variables de entorno ANDROID_HOME y JAVA_HOME creo que es ahi donde puede estar mi problema

Comment: @DavidIriondo estas trabajando en Windows ? https://www.softzone.es/windows-10/como-se-hace/cambiar-path-variables-entorno/

Comment: Estoy trabajando en mac OS

Comment: https://support.apple.com/es-us/guide/terminal/apd382cc5fa-4f58-4449-b20a-41c53c006f8f/mac