# Fallo al instalar React native(Android studio)

Tags: android-studio, react-native, macos

Hola estoy instalando react native y a la hora de arrancar la aplicacion con android studio me aparece el siguiente error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En este punto estoy perdido no se a causa de que, he seguido los pasos de la documentacion y todo perfecto para Xcode , pero pasa esto con Android studio

Esta es mi lista de dispositivos y como se puede ver no esta vacia, pero no lo detecta:

```
➜  AwesomeProject emulator -list-avds
Pixel_3a_API_29
```

Answer (score 0):

El primer error que te da indica que no tienes emuladores instalados. Se referirá a que no tienes instalado Android Studio por ejemplo. Yo no lo tengo instalado y me funciona por que lo instalé con expo.io Échale un vistazo a esta pregunta/respuesta:

[Error al correr proyecto react native](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/409868/error-al-correr-proyecto-react-native/410089#410089)

Comment: Sisi claro, lo tengo, de hecho es que no detecta el emulador, he intentado arrancar primero el emulador y despues  React-native, pero tampoco, entonces es eso, no esta establecida la conexion y nose por que

Comment: Si es algun problema de alguna ruta que deba de añadir, nose... si alguien sabe alguna solucion , estaria bien, gracias!!